# Email pandas dataframe as csv attachment

Tags: python, pandas, win32com

So, I have a cleaned dataframe that I'm trying to export as an attachment using Outlook.
In this case, I'm using win32.client to send an email.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'abc@abc.com'
mail.Subject = 'Sample Email'
mail.Body = '''Please find data attached and below.\n
Hello! This is the body'''
mail.Attachments.Add(Source=df_merged.to_csv)
```

I'm trying to attach df as the attachment in csv or excel. I'm getting this error.

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'method' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
```

I figured out that this only accepts a system address for the attachment and not the address of a dataframe object. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What about `Source=df_merged.to_csv()`?

Comment: Naah, the system is looking for a windows path like (Source='C:\User\Documents')

Comment: The challenge is that I don't have to use smtp for the email alerts due to permission issues. I have to use win32 library to send emails from local Outlook.

Comment: Actually create the CSV and then pass the filepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `to_csv` itself function as the parameter:
mail.Attachments.Add(Source=**df_merged.to_csv**)

Use this instead:
`mail.Attachments.Add(Source=df_merged.to_csv())`

You could also temporarily store the Dataframe on the disk and use the path of the file instead. You can then remove it using the `os` package

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the tip!